# Busco un SELECT que combine dos tablas y obtener una lista de todas las combinaciones de sus registros en MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

Tengo una tabla A con los registros: A, B, C
Tengo otra tabla B con los registros: 4, 2, 1
Necesito obtener una lista con los registros combinados: A 4, A 2, A 1, B 4, B 2, B 1, C 4, C 2, C 1
Como seria un SELECT para obtener esto ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás hablando de un producto cartesiano:

```
SELECT * FROM A,B;
```

Aunque no sea muy habitual encontrárselo, es muy útil que lo conozcas para resolver ciertas situaciones que se resuelven con este operador.

También lo puedes construir con un `JOIN`, sin `ON` ni `USING`, en vez de la `,`.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Exactamente lo que necesitaba.